# Resque workers fail immediately: undefined method `write' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I am using Resque (and resque-scheduler) in my Rails app to run a recurring job. This was working fine for me, until today. I made some code changes, which I thought were unrelated, but now every worker fails before the perform method is even entered (checked with a debug statement). The same worker method works fine when I run it in the rails console. It only fails via resque on the development localhost (Postgres DB).

The error shown in the resque console for the failed worker is:

```
Exception
    NoMethodError
Error
    undefined method `write' for nil:NilClass
```

There is no additional stack trace for the error. Any idea why this is failing?

Additional info:

lib/tasks/resque.rake

```
# Resque tasks
require 'resque/tasks'
require 'resque_scheduler/tasks'

namespace :resque do
  task :setup do
    require 'resque'
    require 'resque_scheduler'
    require 'resque/scheduler'

    # you probably already have this somewhere
    Resque.redis = 'localhost:6379'

    # If you want to be able to dynamically change the schedule,
    # uncomment this line.  A dynamic schedule can be updated via the
    # Resque::Scheduler.set_schedule (and remove_schedule) methods.
    # When dynamic is set to true, the scheduler process looks for
    # schedule changes and applies them on the fly.
    # Note: This feature is only available in >=2.0.0.
    #Resque::Scheduler.dynamic = true

    # The schedule doesn't need to be stored in a YAML, it just needs to
    # be a hash.  YAML is usually the easiest.
    Resque.schedule = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/resque_schedule.yml")

    # If your schedule already has +queue+ set for each job, you don't
    # need to require your jobs.  This can be an advantage since it's
    # less code that resque-scheduler needs to know about. But in a small
    # project, it's usually easier to just include you job classes here.
    # So, something like this:
    # require 'jobs'
  end
end

task "resque:setup" => :environment do
  #ENV['QUEUE'] = '*'

  Resque.before_fork = Proc.new { ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection }
end
```

config/resque.yml

```
development: localhost:6379
test: localhost:6379:1
staging: redis1.se.github.com:6379
fi: localhost:6379
production: redis1.ae.github.com:6379
```

initializers/resque.rb

```
rails_root = Rails.root || File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../..'
rails_env = Rails.env || 'development'

resque_config = YAML.load_file(rails_root.to_s + '/config/resque.yml')
Resque.redis = resque_config[rails_env]

# This will make the tabs show up.
require 'resque_scheduler'
require 'resque_scheduler/server'
```

config/resque_schedule.yml

```
populate_game_data:
  # you can use rufus-scheduler "every" syntax in place of cron if you prefer
  every: 1m
  # By default the job name (hash key) will be taken as worker class name.
  # If you want to have a different job name and class name, provide the 'class' option
  class: PopulateDataWorker
  queue: high
  args:
  description: "This job populates the game and data"
```

Should note that the above files were not changed between working and non-working state.

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? The code for your worker class would be a good start.

Comment: Can you rollback the changes or review them?, with no info about them, it is hard to guess what went wrong.

Comment: @sgrif I don't think the worker class code is relevant, since it fails before it even gets executed. Just to confirm, I commented out all the code in the worker method and I get the same result.

Comment: @d33pika One of the higher level changes I made was starting to use serialized attributes (stored in 'text' fields in the DB).

Comment: @Kohanz Well can you give us some code where you're queueing it? Maybe something from your initializers? That error would imply to me that $stdin is getting set to nil somewhere, or something that expects a file isn't getting it -- But I can't help without seeing some of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had the same issue this morning, and we pinned it down to a gem update by New Relic. 
Version 3.5.6.46 of newrelic_rpm was yanked on rubygems, but it was somehow installed by bundle update.

They are still on the beta track for 3.5.6 and had some issues with Resque. See https://github.com/newrelic/rpm/commit/e81889c2bce97574ec682dafee12015e13ccb2e1

The fix was to add '~> 3.5.5.38' in our Gemfile for newrelic_rpm

Comment: That did it. Thank you! Out of curiosity, what pointed you to the new relic RPM?